# Looking to extract a non-uniform part of a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I received some help from a peer building a formula but I'm lost on what to do next. I have tried a few things like adding another IFERROR clause to cover the missing data, but I can't seem to make it work.

A sample:

```
Column A (input)
*Some text and numbers* VM-123  *Some text and numbers*
*Some text and numbers* VM 1234  *Some text and numbers*
*Some text and numbers* VM-12345: *Some text and numbers*
*Some text and numbers* WELEV-12 *Some text and numbers*
*Some text and numbers* WELEV 123 *Some text and numbers*
*Some text and numbers* WELEV-1234. *Some text and numbers*

Column B (output)
VM-123
VM
VM-12345:
WELEV-12
WELEV 
WELEV-1234.
```

The formula I used to extract these codes:

```
=IFERROR(IFERROR(LEFT(RIGHT(A1;LEN(A1)-FIND("WELEV";A1)+1);FIND(" ";RIGHT(A1;LEN(A1)-FIND("WELEV";A1)+1)));LEFT(RIGHT(A1;LEN(A1)-FIND("VM";A1)+1);FIND(" ";RIGHT(A1;LEN(A1)-FIND("VM";A1)+1))));" ")
```

The main problem is the second and fifth extraction in Column B cut the code off at the space. Here I need the entire code and numbers with the space in between, it doesn't have to be replaced by a hyphen. I think this is because it searches from the left for a space, and encounters the one in the middle before the one at the end.

Another minor issue is the third and last extraction in Column B also included punctuation marks, because there isn't a space at the end I assume. If it's possible, I don't want to include those punctuation marks if they are at the end of the code.

To be honest at this point it goes over my head. I understand generally what parts of the function do, but I'm missing the total picture to finetune this formula. I just started out a few weeks ago and am learning. If anyone can elaborate, I would be very thankful.

Mark

Comment: Do your strings always end with a numeric value? And can there be a value like, lets say: `WELEV-1234 56` (note the space)

Comment: Are you discounting VBA? Think I would use regular expressions for this (with a bit more sample data).

Comment: @JvdV Thank you for replying. I have checked the data and I only have seen WELEV-1234  8. (These are two spaces, which might be beneficial). In all other cases after the code is a space followed by a letter, not a number. All the variants that occur are mentioned in my small sample.

Comment: @SJR Thank you for your comment. If it is possible I want to leave VBA out of the equation. All variants are mentioned in the small sample above, and after the code comes a space and then letters. As I mentioned in the comment above this one, after the space comes almost always a letter, and in a few cases two spaces followed by a number.

Comment: You should not simply use `*Some text and numbers*` in your example but rather a more realistic sample data that contains all possible variations of the strings which may or may not include similar characters, spaces or symbols as your target value. It is not an easy task as you know so you may well waste some contributor's time coming up a solution which does not cover all possible cases.

Comment: @Terry W thank you for informing me, at that moment I thought it could be any alphanumeric characters when I posted this, it is quite a large dataset. Nonetheless the contributor was able to solve it with my data provided. Next time I'll provide more accurate sample data.

Comment: @Hoxus how about replacing your current examples with some more realistic examples and confirm if `:` and `.` are the only special symbols in the string? If not please confirm how many special symbols could be used in the string?

Answer (score 2):

Assume your data put in `A1:A6` (Input)

In `B1` (Output), formula copied down :

```
=IFERROR(IFERROR(MID(A1,FIND("WELEV",A1),6),MID(A1,FIND("VM",A1),3))&LOOKUP(9^9,0+MID(A1,MIN(FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},A1&1/17,LOOKUP(9^9,FIND({"VM","WELEV"},A1)))),ROW($1:$20))),"")
```

Result in B1:B6 (Output) :

```
B1: VM-123
B2: VM 1234
B3: VM-12345
B4: WELEV-12
B5: WELEV 123
B6: WELEV-1234
```

Comment: Thank you for this elaborate formula and I am absolutely intrigued, I got it to work and got consistent results throughout the dataset. Great!

Comment: Sorry to bother you bosco_yip, there is one anomaly I noticed: "WELEV-3265:" is extracted as WELEV-135,958333333333 as with a few others that end in colons. I'm curious why this happens and if it is fixable. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Hoxus you should post the full string otherwise how can anyone tell why it went wrong?

Comment: @Terry W, the formula is posted above, or am I missing something?

Comment: @Hoxus I mean you should post the full text string that bossco_yip's answer is not returning the desired result. I am not asking you to post your formula.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of it; here my attempt (considerably long formula)

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""),":",""),MIN(IFERROR(SEARCH({"VM","WELEV"},SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""),":","")),"")),MIN(IF(MID(UPPER(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""),":","")),ROW(INDEX(A:A,IFERROR(SEARCH("VM",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""),":",""))+2,SEARCH("WELEV",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""),":",""))+5)):INDEX(A:A,LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""),":","")))),1)=TRANSPOSE(CHAR(ROW($65:$90))),ROW(INDEX(A:A,IFERROR(SEARCH("VM",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""),":",""))+2,SEARCH("WELEV",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""),":",""))+5)):INDEX(A:A,LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""),":","")))),""))-MIN(IFERROR(SEARCH({"VM","WELEV"},SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""),":","")),""))))
```

> *The formula is an array formula and needs to be confirmed through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>*

The formula would be considerably shorter if you don't mind to include the dot and semi-colon and would just `SUBSTITUTE` that in another column.

Either way, the output looks like:

[image]

Comment: Very nice work JvdV, I will confirm the formula with my dataset.

Comment: @Hoxus, let me know :)